# ASP.NET Validator Issues For New .NET 4.5 Textbox Modes

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation

I am using the "New" number textbox mode that is available for sites running .NET 4.5 and I am attempting to validate user input with the asp.net validation controls. I am able to validate that the number chosen falls within a specified range (1-254) with the following REGEX expression:

```
^([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|2[5][0-6])$
```

This expression should also validate that the input is of numeric value and does not contain characters. For some reason the validation for the range works appropriately, but if I input `"A"` or any other character string it will return as valid.

If I remove the `TextMode="Number"` property from the textbox everything works as it should. Has anyone else run across this bug?

If I access the site in an older browser which ignores the new textbox textmode, validation works appropriately.

Comment: Don't use regex to validate number in a range. It is very unreadable.

Comment: Have you tried range validator instead?

Comment: I used the range validator but ran into the same issue where it would not invalidate letters. I thought that by switching to REGEX it might fix the issue, but it does not seem to be the case. I could absolutely switch back to range validators but it would leave me with the same issue.

Comment: can you not validate that it is a number AND validate that it is in range? Two validators on one input is possible yeah? In the past, for example, I'd have to validate with a 'required' and a regex validator when validating emails.

Comment: This may be an option, I think for now I just stuck with using the old textbox modes because the new modes are not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want two validators for this textbox, one, that the entered value is a number (comparevalidator with operator set to data type check and type set to integer), and one that the number is within a given range (rangevalidator with appropriate min/max values).

Is there a reason that you need to combine both checks in a single validator?

Comment: I don't believe setting the textbox mode to "Number" causes validation. It simply extends the box with arrows to increment/decrement the value. You can still type in a letter or other symbol if you want.